# "Application not installed" error and API levels

Tags: android, api

I've developed my first Android app, and have successfully deployed it to my Galaxy S4. The app was developed for API level 19.

When I tried to install it on an older phone (HTC Desire, running Android 2.3) I got an error saying that the apk could not be parsed. I guessed that this was because the API level for the app was 19, so revised this in my Android manifest to API level 9, regenerated the APK, then tried installing it on the HTC again. This time it tried to install the app, advised me of the permissions being requested, but then gave the error message "Application not installed"

Can anyone suggest what my options are from here? My Android manifest is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ian.mealtimer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <application
        android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.MealTimerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.PresetItemsActivity"
            android:label="@string/preset_item" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.MealActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meal" >

            <!-- android:parentActivityName="com.ian.mealtimer.MainActivity" > -->
            <!-- <meta-data -->
            <!-- android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" -->
            <!-- android:value="com.ian.mealtimer.MainActivity" /> -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.MealItemActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meal_item" >
            android:parentActivityName="com.ian.mealtimer.MealActivity" >



            <!-- <meta-data -->
            <!-- android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" -->
            <!-- android:value="com.ian.mealtimer.MealActivity" /> -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.MealItemDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meal_item_detail"
            android:parentActivityName="com.ian.mealtimer.MealItemActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ian.mealtimer.MealItemActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.SelectPresetItemActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_preset_item" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.SavedMealsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_saved_meals" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ian.mealtimer.SetMealTimersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_meal_timers"
            android:parentActivityName="com.ian.mealtimer.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.ian.mealtimer.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR_SERVICE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your minimum and target are different things. Try setting your minimum to 9 and your target to 19

Comment: Ok I just tried that but got exactly the same error:       <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: for android 2.3 minSdkVersion should be 8. not 9

Comment: @Riad 2.2.x is 8, 2.3 is 9.

Comment: The HTC is running Android 2.3.7. I revised the API down to 8 in any case, but still get the same error.      <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Answer (score 0):

The `Application not installed` occurs when there is a conflict with the old installed app with the new installed app. First of all you installed it first with the api as 19 then installed it again with api as 9 with out uninstalling it first.

**solution:**

Uninstalled the app first then use the `android:minSdkVersion="9"` in the manifest
`

Comment: This app has NEVER been installed successfully on the HTC - only on the Galaxy S4, where it has installed correctly every time. The HTC has failed every installation attempt :0(